# How to refresh Power BI report (schedule) which is deployed in Azure workspace collection

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have created Power BI report, and imported into Azure Workspace Collection, and then embedded the report into my webpage, using api calls...

My question is, I want to refresh the data on a daily basis. How can I refresh the report which is stored in Azure Workspace Collection ?

My data source is SQL Server (Not Azure SQL Database). 
For this, I heard that there is Gateway.

Could you please explain the step by step approach in oder to configure the Gateway and scheduling Power BI report (present in azure) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read this article that describes the [Power BI Data Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-personal-gateway/), when you need it especially.

To use this gateway, you need a Power BI Pro license.

Comment: i am not publish the report to power bi portal(dashboard). i exported(.pbix) to azure power bi workspace collection.what ever explained in that article applicable only when you publish report to  power bi portal(dashboard). then how can I refresh the report which is stored in Azure power bi Workspace Collection

Comment: this is the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/power-bi-embedded-get-started-sample) for embedded report in web application using azure power bi workspace colllection.

Comment: Did you make the sample work in your environment ? I think you have to make your report work in the Power BI portal, make the sample work with your resources, and then use your report in the sample.

Comment: so there is noway to refresh dataset which is present in azure power bi workspace colllection? then what is the use of azure power bi workspace colllection? only static view embedded reports?